# Как в prepared statmet передать List стрингов

Tags: java, mysql, sql, list, preparedstatement

```
List<String>  description = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("please enter a short description of the booklet (optional)");
    while (true){
        String current = scanner.nextLine();
        if (current.equals(""))break;
        description.add(current);
    }

public void insert( String name,  String release, String publish, ArrayList<String> description) {
    preparedStatement.//????
}
```

Как  сделать так чтобы этот prepare statment получал list стрингов и записывал их в бд?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой пример подправьте с учетом остальных полей.

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into table_name(description) value(?);");
for(String str : description){
    ps.setString(1, str);
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

Comment: А включить потом автокоммит не нужно?

Comment: @RomanDanilov достаточно после транзакций вызывать метод `connection.commit()`. Включать autocommit я бы не советовал, т.к. его отключение может увеличить производительность (если это важно). Более детально написано [тут](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/top-10-jdbc-best-practices-for-java.html)

Comment: То есть у вас после вставки база остается в состоянии с выключенным автокоммитом, и другие приложения, использующие эту СУБД так же работают с выключенным автокоммитом?

Comment: @StasDorozhko спасибо за ответ. Есть только одна проблема. Эти стринги должны быть записаны в один кортеж

Comment: @RomanDanilov нет. У других приложений другое подключение.

Comment: @Артем что за кортеж? В 1 запись БД?

Comment: @Артем Вы имеете в виду связь в БД "1-ко-многим", где вот этот список связан с одной какой-то записью в другой таблице, правильно?

Comment: @StasDorozhko нет, я имею ввиду что все эти стринги передаются в одно и то же поле например я вожу несколько строк в консоль из них собирается лист и записывается в description, а сейчас получается так, что каждая строка создает новые строки таблицы и записывается в них. Надеюсь не замудрил...

Comment: @Артем Тогда можно все строки из списка объединить в одну строку и записать в одну ячейку БД. Но лучше решить это со связью "1-ко-многим", это будет правильней со стороны нормализации БД. То есть, получить какой-то ключ (id) из буклета после записи и в другую таблицу  записывать описание и id буклета, к которому оно относится. Таким способом и выйдет связь один буклет ко многим описаниям.